# Putting links inside the menu buttons

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to create a menu out of six buttons, placed upon a large background image. How do I get the link texts to stay inside the buttons? This is the code so far (I wish to keep using this "list method", cause I found it easier to understand than multiple div-statements inside two images...):

```css
ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:510px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-image: url(http://www.returngis.net/wp-content/uploads/pics/demos/grass.jpg);
    z-index:150;
}

ul li
{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" />LINK1</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" />LINK2</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" />LINK3</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" />LINK4</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" />LINK5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your *text links* in anchors, because I suppose you need to make them clickable anyway, then "move them up" using negative margins. Something like this:

```css
ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:510px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-image: url(http://www.returngis.net/wp-content/uploads/pics/demos/grass.jpg);
    z-index:150;
}

ul li
{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:100;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -64px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" /><a>LINK1</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" /><a>LINK2</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" /><a>LINK3</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" /><a>LINK4</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="50" height="100" /><a>LINK5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>LINK1</li>
    <li>LINK2</li>
    <li>LINK3</li>
    <li>LINK4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:510px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-image: url(http://www.returngis.net/wp-content/uploads/pics/demos/grass.jpg);
    z-index:150;
}

ul li
{
   background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
   background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:100;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/d3Lw4hjq/

Answer (score 0):

You can `absolute`ly position the `img` in the `li`, and change the `padding` on the `li` to `margin`, then use `display: inline-flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to position the text over the `img`

```css
ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:510px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-image: url(http://www.returngis.net/wp-content/uploads/pics/demos/grass.jpg);
    z-index:150;
}

ul li
{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    margin:20px;
    z-index:100;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>LINK1</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>LINK2</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>LINK3</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>LINK4</li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>LINK5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you either set the images as the background of the li's, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>LINK1</li>
    <li>LINK2</li>
    <li>LINK3</li>
    <li>LINK4</li>
    <li>LINK5</li>
</ul>
```

And for the css:

```
li { background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'); }
```

Or you absolute position the images, like this:

```
ul li
{
    position: relative;
}

ul li img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v78501mn/

Just a small note, if you have "display: inline-block" on your li's, "float: left" is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I just didn't realize that you were able to customize the behaviour of the img-tag by putting in additional css code. Really cool! I'm still new at this, but I fully understand all this solutions! Thank you!